# css for xpath related to nth sibling under header element

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to get css for below xpath

```
//*[@id="key-facts-heading"]/h4[1]/text()[2]
```

but couldn't understand what to do after `#key-facts-heading`

I don't understand why chrome console doesn't have css selector but it has xpath, is there another way to get css from chrome console directly ?

Note:

Earlier I was relying on https://cssify.appspot.com/ but this website is not more working with error "

> Access to XMLHttpRequest ...from origin 'https://cssify.appspot.com'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

"

[image]

Comment: Post your Relevant HTML you are looking after css selector?

Comment: @KunduK please check screenshot

Comment: @DebanjanB please re-open this question as it's not same as one you marked as duplicate

Comment: @vikramvi Can you update the question how your question _css for xpath containing text() method_ is different from the dup marked discussion?

Comment: @DebanjanB can you check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated :**

To get **2,43,078.87 Cr** as the output,

```
// Target the element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#key-facts-heading > h4:nth-of-type(1) > span"));
// Get the following text using a JS Executor
String text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent.trim()", element);
System.out.println(text);
```

**Note :** 2,43,078.87 Cr is within `<h4>` and not `<span>`

Comment: How would `/text()[2]` convert into `span:nth-of-type(2)`? Where did the **`span`** come from?

Comment: Please read my answer again and that should answer your question

Comment: @WilfredClement I've added screenshot for the HTML,  can you please have a look

Comment: @vikramvi: Updated the ans, please check

Comment: @WilfredClement Thanks for quick help.